# PHP curl redirect moved permanently

Tags: php, curl

I'm downloading blog posts for analysis and after 10 pages of results I'm getting a strange redirect to the site's homepage rather than to the 10th page of results. Going to the 10th page in my browser works just fine.

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.russellmoore.com/category/article/page/10");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($status);
```

Executing this code redirects my script to http://www.russellmoore.com/.

Comment: What about when you comment out the user agent? I got all the way to page 20. Maybe they're doing something based on that.

Comment: Yes, that works! So frustrating though, because another blog I'm downloading from fails if I don't have the user agent. Any thoughts on why the user agent matters?

Comment: No idea at all, frankly. You could test with various user agents. Is the one you used the one your browser sends, for example? It might be the fact you've sent one at all...

Answer (score 0):

As Daren pointed out, removing the user agent worked. However, because another blog I was downloading from required a user agent, I changed it to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:17.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/17.0');
```

This solution worked for both blogs.